# Liferay not sending emails

Tags: java, email, groovy, liferay

I'm currently experiencing an issue with Liferay, where it is not sending emails. There is an `AuthenticationFailedException` in the log, but not any more specifics (e.g. the error message received from the remote server). I have created a script to test, but get no exceptions or errors.

```
def from = new InternetAddress("user@example.com", "user@ecample.com")
def to = new InternetAddress ("other@example.com", "other@example.com")
def mail = new MailMessage(from, to, "subject", "message", false)
MailServiceUtil.sendEmail(mail)
```

How can I check what the cause is and resolve the issue?

**Update**
The email is set up to send via office 365 (smtp.office365.com) and the credentials used work when I log in using the website. When I get the properties, they are set as:

mail.smtp.session.mail.smtp.host : smtp.office365.com
mail.session.smtp.port : 587
mail.session.smtp.user = user@example.com
mail.session.smtp.password = password

They are set via script when the password changes as the server administration page is blank.

```
def session = MailServiceUtil.getSession()
def properties = session.getProperties()
properties.setProperty(PropsKeys.MAIL_SESSION_MAIL, "password")
MailServiceUtil.clearSession()
```

The credentials are fine, but exceptions can occur for other reasons.

Thanks

Comment: Did you configure a mail server connection? Typically that involves a sender's account, SMTP host and password. Background: With MailServiceUtil you're using Liferay's internal infrastructure, which will use its own configuration. No sane mailserver is going to accept random incoming connections these days and you must configure an outgoing SMTP server.

Comment: It worked recently, so I suspect a possible configuration change. Since try/catch doesn't work, it complicates any custom portlets that send emails since it is a void method with no thrown exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm have tried to configure Liferay smtp settings to connect office 365 (smtp.office365.com) but it's not possibile due to TLS requirements. Bundled java mail engine cannot work with some modern smtp.

Install a postfix locally and configure it as relay smtp to smtp.office365.com, then switch Liferay to easy localhost:25 smtp.

Comment: When it worked before for me, I used `session.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")`

Comment: postfix is better way

Comment: You might just need to configure the trust relationship properly, e.g. import the root certificate that O365 uses on its SMTP server.